# Basic Question about Bluetooth Service Discovery Protocol

Tags: bluetooth

I'm hoping someone can clarify something for me.

When I look at what characteristics my HID device has to implement, I go to https://www.bluetooth.com/xml-viewer/?src=https://www.bluetooth.com/wp-content/uploads/Sitecore-Media-Library/Gatt/Xml/Services/org.bluetooth.service.human_interface_device.xml and can see, for instance, that I need to implement the "Report Map" characteristic (uuid 0x2A4B).

Okay makes sense so far.

However, when I go here: https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/assigned-numbers/service-discovery/

I now see an attribute called HIDDescriptorList under (Attribute ID 0x0206) - which is basically the same thing I'm pretty sure as Report Map. There is other such duplication in this table as well.

I'm clearly missing something. How does SDP play into all this?